# Java spotless plugin with starred imports

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, swagger-codegen, spotless

I have a swagger openapi yml definition to generate apis. But this plugin incorporates unused imprts into the generated files. I could erase most of them by spotless plugin but I can't stop swagger to make starred imports  (`import javax.validation.constraints.*;`) which isn't handled by spotless. Here is my spotless configuration:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.36.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <java>
                    <includes>
                        <include>target/somewhere/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <importOrder/>
                    <removeUnusedImports/>
                </java>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>apply</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Do you know any worrkround for this? Either stop swagger starred imports generation or any spotless configuration to delete unused starred imports are welcome.

I am using IntelliJ v2022.3.3

Comment: I'm in exactly the same boat, did you ever get a resolution for this?

Comment: @LostShepherd Actually I didn't get any proper solution from spotless point of view. I started to investigate java openapi code generator where I recognised that the starred imports are hard coded based on certain templates. You can find the templates here: 
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main 
So if I manipulated the templates then I would get the proper result. But my consideration is taking the responsibility of code generation logic is higher than leaving starred imports in the code. So I left it as it is.